# Merging large amount of adjacent polygons based on attribute field using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, identity

I have overlaid two shapefiles with the tool "Identity".

Thus thousands of slivers were created. I eliminated slivers that are smaller than a certain area. But there are still several thousands left. I can not just eliminate them because it would merge them to neighboring polygons with the biggest area. In my case, this would set some forest to grassland.

I want to merge them based on attribute field, how can I achieve it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Integrate?: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/integrate.htm

Comment: The tool to merge polygons based on attribute values is Dissolve.

Comment: How about Dissolve in ESRI ArcMap? Fabulous tool. I did a test with exactly similar dataset, ArcMap dissolve is lightning fast and gives better result compared to QGis equivalent and PostGIS' group by SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Dissolve tool for this task. As it is described in the help it should dissolve your polygons the way you need it. You can select a Dissolve_Field which in your case should be the attribute with the landcover type.

[image: ArcMAP help image description of the Dissolve tool]

Remember to check or uncheck the multipart feature box depending if you want to have separate polygons or only one with multiple parts.